# Подставить текущего пользователя в форму

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель:

```
class worker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='возраст')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='город')
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='skype')
    icq = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='ICQ')
```

Есть форма

```
 class worker_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = worker
        exclude = ('user', )
```

есть вид

```
 def add_worker(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = worker_form(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.user = request.user # Как сделать что бы подставился текущий юзер?      
             form.save()
        return render_to_response('message.html', {})
```

Если делать так то вылетает ошибка

```
worker_worker.user_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался проблема была в том что

```
exclude = ('user', )
```

совсем убирает поле из формы(я думал что только не отображает)
удалил эту строку и написал

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data.update({'user':request.user.id})
    form = worker_form(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.user= request.user
        form.save()
```

и всё заработало